# Como uso uma mesma sessão no laravel para todos os subdomínios?

Tags: laravel

Estou querendo fazer um login em um subdomínio users.meudominio.com. Para testar a sessão, estou apenas exibindo o que digito no campo login na tela com o código no controller:

```
if($request->session()->has('session_login'))
   return view("welcome", ["session_login" => $request->session()->get('session_login')]);
```

Depois disso um simples {{ $session_login }} exibe corretamente o que digitei. Porém também quero usar esta mesma sessão no subdomínio clinic.domain.com, mas não está funcionando. Coloquei o seguinte código no controller deste segundo subdomínio:

```
if($request->session()->has('session_login'))
    View::share('session_login', $request->session()->get('session_login'));
else
    View::share('session_login', "BBB");
```

Mas sempre exibe apenas "BBB" no segundo subdomínio. Já configurei o arquivo sessions.php nas duas aplicações, colocando `'domain' => ".i9technology.com.br"`, e também estou usando o Homestead. O que falta pra essa sessão funcionar nos dois subdomínios?

Comment: Amigo acho que esse artigo vai te ajudar: https://medium.com/@pagcosma/multi-subdomain-sessions-in-laravel-40fd31b199fa

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30407141/3096922) do SOEN, basta modificar o arquivo `config/session.php`

Procure a seguinte linha:

```
  'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
```

Então coloque `.i9technology.com.br`.

Uma nota na resposta diz que é necessário limpar os cookies do navegador para que as alterações tenha efeito.

Lembre-se também de limpar o cache de configurações:

```bsh
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score -1):

- Capture o `ID` da sessão `Session::getId()` no Domínio A
- Envie o `ID` capturado via `HTTP POST` para o Domínio B
- Receba este valor no Domínio B `$sessionid_from_domainA = \Input::get('ID');`
- Set no ID da sessão no Domínio B `Session::setId($sessionid_from_domainA)`
- Por fim, `Session::start()` no Domínio B

Comment: Não funcionou, continua da mesma forma, mas fiz algumas mudanças. Primeiro alterei os dois session.php, onde tinha `'domain' => ".domain.com.br"` ficou `'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),`, pois percebi que da forma que tava antes a sessão não funcionava nem no próprio domínio A. Segundo, fiz todas estas alterações (peguei o id da sessão, passei via GET, usei setId e start no domínio B) mas o param session_login não foi passado. Dei um print em Session::getId() no domínio B e realmente printou o id certo (que veio via GET), mas o Session::get('session_login') não passou.

Comment: Pelo menos no código que você postou, não está setando nada na sessão para `session_login`, você pode primeiro setar algo ou postar o local onde está fazendo isso? (no códgo postado você apenas verifica se exste e envia para view, depois tenta utilizar no domínio B)

Comment: outro detalhe, o trecho `'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null)`, faz com que a aplicação busque o valor `SESSION_DOMAIN` no seu arquivo `.env`, localizado na raiz do seu projeto, ele vai continuar fixo da mesma forma. Ainda assim, creio que não esteja afetando em nada no que estamos tentando fazer!

Comment: Estas são as três linhas de código que estou usando para guardar na sessão: `$session_id = Session::getId();$request->session()->put('session_login', $request->login); return redirect("http://clinic.i9technology.com.br?session_id=$session_id");`. E este o código do controller que recebe no Domínio B: `$session_id = $request->session_id;Session::setId($session_id);Session::start();if($request->session()->has('session_login'))
   View::share('session_login', $request->session()->get('session_login')); else View::share('session_login', "AAA");return view("index");`. Na tela só printa AAA

Comment: E ta setando normal na sessão, pois na página welcome no domínio A é exibido normalmente o `session_login`. Mas quando passo pro B não é, mesmo passando o id da sessão e recebendo com o código acima. O mesmo if é usado no domínio A, mas dá `true` e cai dentro do IF. Já tentei também colocar um `View::share('session_login', Session::get('session_login'))` nesse else, mas nada foi printado, ficou em branco.